# Accessing XML data: Same element name but differentiation by attribute

Tags: xml, attributes

I have a multi-language XML file containing English and German strings which have the same element name `type` but are distinguished from each other by the `lang` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>
  <type lang="en">package design</type>
  <type lang="de">verpackung</type>
</project>
```

How can I access these information separately?

`$xml->type;` echoes out the content of the first `type` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML, there are multiple ways to get required node.Either you can iterate through the the innermost parent or you can create your xpath and parse accordingly.

```
<type lang="de">verpackung</type>
```

Suppose you have to fetch the text content pertaining to german lang,

xpath : project/type[@lang="en"]
This directly takes you to the required node.

You may also use jaxb for that.

Comment: Thanks! `$xml->xpath(" type[@lang='en'] ")` works for me!